# How to fix "Wrong response from the webhook: 301 Moved Permanently" in Telegram Webhook response?

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot

I'm trying to create telegram bot on Laravel with [php-telegram-bot](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core). I have installed webhook and now I get a message:

```
{"ok": true,
"result": {
"url": "https://.../api/telegram/hook/",
"has_custom_certificate": true,
"pending_update_count": 15,
"last_error_date": 1549043620,
"last_error_message": "Wrong response from the webhook: 301 Moved Permanently",
"max_connections": 40
}
}
```

What does it mean? I know what is 301 error mean, but can't understand what steps needed to solve this problem.

My controller:

```
public function hook()
    {
      $commands_paths = [
            app_path() . '/Services/Telegram/Bots/Bitbd_BOT/Commands',
      ];
      try {
          // Create Telegram API object
          $telegram = new Telegram($this->bot_api_key, $this->bot_username);
          TelegramLog::initErrorLog(storage_path() . "/{$this->bot_username}_error.log");
          TelegramLog::initDebugLog(storage_path() . "/{$this->bot_username}_debug.log");
          TelegramLog::initUpdateLog(storage_path() . "/{$this->bot_username}_update.log");
          // Add commands paths containing your custom commands
          $telegram->addCommandsPaths($commands_paths);
          $telegram->enableLimiter();
          // Handle telegram webhook request
          $handle = $telegram->handle();

      } catch (TelegramException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
      }
    }
```

API routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'telegram'], function () {
    Route::get('hook/set', 'TelegramController@setWebhook');
    Route::any('hook','TelegramController@hook');
});
```

Some interesting: /api/telegram/hook correctly works only with ANY or GET option, POST method return empty page with vue, and i don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a middleware in app/Http/Middleware/PreflightResponse.php

And paste this code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class PreflightResponse
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next )
    {
        if ($request->getMethod() === "OPTIONS") {
            return response('');
        }
return $next($request);
     }
 }
```

Then in app/Http/Kernel.php, add in the global variable $middleware:

```
protected $middleware = [
    Middleware\PreflightResponse::class,
];
```

This is a general solution, but you can specify as a named middleware and using in your routes.

That happens because of CORS and its security measures.
I hope that could help :D

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a problem in your webhook url, please check it again, And make sure that is correct and exists in your server.

Even `https://example.com/folder/` is different with `https://example.com/folder` and you have to use `/` at the end of the address (In my case, I gave that error because of `/`).